# php session not working for popup login

Tags: php, session

I am not good at this and have been trying but its not working. I don't know why the `get.php` is index page and its file `header.php` has another file `login.php`. I don't know why the session is not working the way I think it should. Footer should show `username` when logged in but it doesn't.

**get.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include("header.php");?>
    <?php include("menu.php");?>
    <?php include("slider.php");?>
    <?php include("content.php");?>
    <div id="footer">
      <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['currentuser'])==true)
        {
            echo"$username";
        }
        else
        {
            echo" not logged in ";
        }
      ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include("connect.php");

  if(isset($_POST['login']))
  {
      $username=$_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'];
      $query="select * from user where username='$username' AND password='$password'";  
      $run=mysql_query($query);

      if(mysql_num_rows($run)>0)
      {
          $_SESSION['currentuser']=true; 
          header("Location:get.php");
      }
      else
      {
          header("Location:get.php#loginfail"); 
      }
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['currentuser']) && $_SESSION['currentuser'] == true)
```

Also remember to include `session_start()` on each page which requires sessions.

Comment: whenever i use session_start() on each page i get the error

A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: Make sure you aren't including it twice then. Do you have session_start() in get.php AND header.php?

Comment: the header.php is within that index page(get.php) do i need to use session_start() in both of them ??

Comment: No, only one, whichever is loaded first, so get.php

Comment: and inside header.php there is login.php is that correct or i have to have a separate page for login 

the order is get.php(1st homepage kinda) then it has got header.php(file included) then it has got login.php(file included inside header,php)

Comment: Only once per page load, so only in get.php in this case.

Comment: sir i want to get login like of this site www.flipkart.com

Answer (score 1):

Sessions can only be accessed after a page refresh when they are set. You'll need to reload the page to be able to access the session variables.

Another note: Everywhere you want you use any kind of session, you'll need to start the session with:

```
session_start();
```

So your `get.php` file would look something like this:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="all">
  </head>

.....etc
```

Comment: sir i want to get the login like of this site www.flipkart.com